# Force an applyBinding in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, data-binding, mvvm, knockout.js

I'm using [knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/) to bind a dom-element to a view-model and everything works great the first time a view-model is applied to the dom-element.

Later on a very similar view-model is applied to the same dom-element but the bindings won't update - probably because knockout believes it is the same view-model as before.

Is there a way to force knockout to apply the new view-model and discard the old view-model?

Comment: can you provide a markup/code snippet?

Comment: MVVM is MVC for WPF, IYKWIM LOL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most common approach is to use the template binding.  It would look something like:

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'mainTmpl', data: myData }"></div>


var viewModel = {
    myData: ko.observable(),
}
```

Now, you can set myData to your new view model like:  `viewModel.myData(newData)` and the template binding will handle re-rendering your content based on the new data.

Otherwise, you can do something like call: `ko.cleanNode(yourRootElement)` (or pass document) and then `ko.applyBindings(yourNewViewModel)` to remove the bindings and apply them to a new view model.